# Stop quotes from being escaped in zend where

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have simple table of hashes with 3 columns . Id is an email address.

Now, I want to retrieve the hash given id and type.

I do this:

```
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select();
$select->where('id=?', $id)->where('type=?', $type);
```

And I get

```
SELECT "hashes".* FROM "hashes" WHERE (id=\'randomemail@randomurl.com\') AND (type=\'email\')
```

instead of

```
SELECT "hashes".* FROM "hashes" WHERE (id='randomemail@randomurl.com') AND (type='email')
```

I have played around with quote and quoteInto, but it keeps escaping the quotes. Everywhere I look, it seems this should not be happening. Where could I be going wrong?

The same query works if type and id are integers though [in which case there are no quotes required]

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that $id, $type is not quoted before using in the statement?

Comment: Yes. I did echo $id.$type just before the where and I got randomemail@randomurl.comemail. No quotes.

Comment: select() uses `quoteInto()` internally. All I can figure is that you are somehow picking up an extra set of single quotes somewhere. Try changing the query so that it doesn't use `select()`. Might shed some light.

Comment: uhm magic quotes enabled? :-)

Comment: Nope, magic quotes disabled. I ll try doing an update and see if it changes anything..

Comment: try a clean query and see what happens `$result = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll("id = $id AND type = $type");` This will at least tell if it's the data being passed or unexpected behavior in select().

Comment: Hum sounds crazy but is it possible that " ' " is part of your string? like: ' 'TEST' ' ?

Comment: @RockyFord - insert worked. So did fetchAll ($this->getDbTable()->fetchAll("id = '$id' AND type = '$type'");) and update. So it is a problem with select. I can use fetchAll to solve my current problem I guess. But it ll be nice to understand what is happening with select..

Comment: Actually, I need to use orWhere for another table, for which I need to use select. So, I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the query was with the code after the $select was created. Even though the quotes seem escaped, the select works fine when used with fetchAll or fetchRow.

The following snippet worked correctly,

```
    $select = $this->getDbTable()->select();
    $select->where('id=?', $id)->where('type=?', $type);;
    $hash = $this->getDbTable()->fetchRow($select)->toArray();
```

even though $select->__toString() showed

```
SELECT "hashes".* FROM "hashes" WHERE (id=\'someemail@gmail.com\') AND (type=\'default\') LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what was the original problem? You never did say what method you were trying to use. If you were trying to use find(), that only works with primary keys. A little late for this observation...

Comment: I couldnt retrieve the values from the database (I was using fetchRow). So I tried debugging by outputting the query, saw the backslashes and assumed that was the problem. Later the problem fixed itself, even though the backslashes remained. I am not exactly sure what fixed it as I was playing around with a lot of things. The code above works fine though.

Comment: Don't you just hate that? Now what do you do next time you have the same problem?... :)

Comment: Haha, atleast I will look beyond the backslashes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
select = $this->getDbTable()->select();
$select->where('id=?',trim($id,"'"))->where('type=?', trim($type,"'"));
```

Comment: Nope, doesnt help. infact even the backslashes exist even if I replaced $id with 'id'